# I don't know why $\int_{-3}^{-2} \frac{dx}{x} = \ln(\frac{2}{3})$

Tags: integration

I don't know why $$\int_{-3}^{-2} \frac{dx} x = \ln \frac{2}{3}.$$ How can i solve this to get that answer?

Comment: Because the anti derivative of 1/x in ln(x)  and then evaluate.

Comment: We have that $\int \frac{dx}{x}=\ln(|x|)+C$, where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

Comment: it is $$\ln(|-2|)-\ln(|-3|)$$

Comment: If you are bothered by the negative limits of integration, make a change of variable $u = -x$ and $du = -dx$ and be careful to change the limits of integration accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$ I = \int_{-3}^{-2}\frac{dx}{x} = \left[\ln |x|\vphantom{\frac11}\right]_{-3}^{-2} = \ln|-2|-\ln|-3| = \ln(2)-\ln(3) = \ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

Notice,

\begin{align}\int_{-3}^{-2}\frac{dx}{x}&=\left[\ln|x| \vphantom{\frac 1 1} \right]_{-3}^{-2}\\
&=\left[\ln|-2|-\ln|-3| \vphantom{\frac 1 1} \right]\end{align}

$$=\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will make you fell better: write $u=-x$ then $$I=\int_3^2\frac{du}{u}.$$